# JMeter modifying output to file from XML Stream

Tags: javascript, xml, string, jmeter

I'm attempting to write a JMeter script which after receiving and XML response from a server, extracts a string from it on the fly (drops the first part of the response) and writes it to a file.

Currently I use a `Save Response Data` to write to `ChannelData_UAT_1` (filename).  All good, it writes happily.

Then I add a `BSF PreProcessor` **BEFORE** it, and use javascript to try and extract the string.  It's a bunch of XML tags, I want everything from "`<Markets>`" onwards.

I use:

```
function extract_markets(str)
{
    marketIndex = str.indexOf("<Markets");
    __log(marketIndex);
    length = str.length;
    marketString = str.substring(markeIndex, length-1);
    return str;
}

vars.put('ChannelData_UAT_1', extract_markets(vars.get('ChannelData_UAT_1')));
```

As far as I can tell, `ChannelData_UAT_1` is the variable the data is in. However this is only mentioned in the `Save Response Data`.  But I can't do it afterwards otherwise it'll have already written to the file.

The current performance is for it to receive the response and write to the file.  No filtering is done - as if my javascript didn't exist.

Anything small or obvious that I've missed? Suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the issue stems from the fact that `ChannelData_UAT_1` is not a variable and how `Save Response Data` works.

`ChannelData_UAT_1` is the file name, not the content of the file.

You need to modify the contents of the "Response".  You can replace the value of the page response with the value of your function.

I *think* the code would look something like this:

```
import org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils; 
import org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult;

prev.setResponseData(extract_markets(vars.get('ChannelData_UAT_1')));
```

Source:
http://www.javadocexamples.com/java_examples/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult/